# Passing a list of parameters from a sql task in SSIS to Web Services URL with a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have a sql query that is generating a list of order numbers...I can place these order numbers individually in the web request URL to Web Services and collect the details of that order. I know how to do that if I had a WSDL file available but the We services is using a RestFul service client and has no WSDL file. I do have a C# code that will work only if I declare the order number and was trying to find out how can I replace this parameter with a DTS variable and use a Foreach loop container to run the rest of the order numbers in the list. Here's the code that I have so far:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Xml;
    /**
    * A test code to consuming a RESTFUL web service. 
     * You need to just parse the xml - either save it in memory/Cache to parse immediatly,
    * or wrire to file and do read and parse it.
    * @author: Jbisht
    */
    namespace JbishtApplication
    {
        class CallWeb
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = null;
                HttpWebResponse response = null;
                String Xml;
                String salesOrderNo = "S3107634";
                String file_ext = ".xml";
                String file_name = salesOrderNo + file_ext;
                String file_path = "C:/";

                // Create the web request - Zones Test Environment - Orderws URL 
                // request = WebRequest.Create("http://test2:8080/orderws/order/" + salesOrderNo) as HttpWebRequest;

                // Create the web request - My instance - Orderws for test only
                request = WebRequest.Create("http://dev2:10580/orderws/order/" + salesOrderNo) as HttpWebRequest;

                // Get response  
                using (response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    // Get the response stream  
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    Xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xdoc.LoadXml(Xml);
                    xdoc.Save(file_path + file_name);  // it will save your response xml to file location;
                }
                // Console xml output  
                Console.WriteLine(Xml); //see if we get the xml response, (YES we do)

                Console.ReadLine(); // Just wrote to keep console window open after writing to console.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What development platform are you comfortable in? You want to run SQL, use the results to loop around and call a web service. I suggest that SSIS is not the simplest tool to do this in. Where do you want to put the resulting XML? Do you have to shred it and put it in the database?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you will need a SQL task as the starting point which gets the list of order numbers from database, and saves query result into a variable of Object type, say "OrderNumberList". Then you have a foreach loop container to loop through the "OrderNumberList" variable, and assigning the current value into another variable "OrderNumber".

(If you have not done all of these before, [HERE](http://coldlogics.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/using-ssis-to-dynamically-create-data-files-from-a-full-result-set/) is a link shows how to loop through a database query result set.)

Place a Script task inside the foreach container, and choose "OrderNumber" as readonly variable, so you can reference the variable in the script. Then in the script,  "OrderNumber" can be referenced as:

```
request = WebRequest.Create("http://dev2:10580/orderws/order/" + 
    ((string) Dts.Variables["OrderNumber"].Value)) as HttpWebRequest;
```